# Protect myself against forgetting to enclose string literals in tr()

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

Qt uses the `tr()` function for internationalization, but it is easy to forget to enclose a string with it, for example writing `label->setText("Name:");` instead of `label->setText(tr("Name:"));`.

I remember reading somewhere that you can make QString show an error unless you explicitly enclose the string in some other way (in QLatin1String if I remember correctly). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` to `DEFINES` in the *.pro file. This will prevent automatic conversion from `char*`. Similarly there is a `QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII` that prevents QStrings being implicitly casted to `char*`.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#converting-between-8-bit-strings-and-unicode-strings for more details

Comment: I use Qt in VS2008 (with the VS addin). I think I don't use a .pro file, it's a vcproj file instead. I assume I just add the define in the vcproj?

Comment: @sashoalm yeah it need to be defined as a macro (as if `/DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` was added to the command line)

Comment: Another question - what should I use when a string should not be translated? `QString s = QLatin1String("C:\");`? What about `QChar`? QChar(':') gives a compile error as well now.

Comment: @sashoalm QChar has fromLatin1() you can use

Comment: For chars you can use QLatin1Char(':')